# "Trend log Object" in BACnet Protocol

Tags: object, bacnet, bacnet4j, bac0, bacpypes

How to read or Display the Trend log Object's properties Value by using the BAC0 library in BACnet protocol ? if anyone know better information, Share proper explanation with good example

I tried with below code & its showing format error

**trend = BAC0.TrendLog('192.162.0.104:58852', device)
print(trend)**

I'm expecting proper format for reading the Trend log Object's Properties values.

Comment: It might possibly help if you mention the vendor name & model name of the device/controller that you are trying to target/read from, in case it's relevant (- it's more likely to be possibly relevant for complex encodings/objects such as 'Trend-Log's).

Are you sure that the device has/is exposing a trend-log (?).

Comment: I am testing Trend Log Object using the BAC0 library. In the BACnet lib written some BACnet devices (Examples) so for those device, I'm checking Trend Log object. But i couldn't get the proper format for getting response from the BACnet device

Comment: If you are saying that you've created the (target / test) devices yourself via the 'BAC0' library, then I assume you have created & exposed a trend-log type object(s) from them/the devices (?).